# 301 redirect using Django urls.py

Tags: django, django-urls

Hi I'm looking to setup some 301 redirects for some urls that have been changed on a site for a client.

I was thinking the following might work:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, RedirectView


from cms.sitemaps import CMSSitemap

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^contact/', include('contact.urls')),
    url(r'^case-study/', include('casestudies.urls')),
    url(r'^contact-us/', include('contact.urls')),
    url(r'^news/', include('news.urls')),
    url(r'^sitemap.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': {'cmspages': CMSSitemap}}),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
    url(r'^robots\.txt$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='robots.txt', content_type='text/plain')),
    url(r'^old-link/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='new-link/'), name='new-link'),
)
```

This seems to make sense to me but this doesn't seem to work. Now i am extremely new to Django so apologies if this is a really simple query.

Comment: `new-link` is view name ?

Comment: Apologies but I'm not sure what you mean? I was thinking that...

old-link/$ (would be the url that needs redirecting)
url='new-link/' (would be the new url to point to)

Comment: So would i be correct in thinking it should be as follows:

    url(r'^'old-link'/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='new-link/'), name='new-link'),

Comment: not, the name should be 'old-link'

Comment: So would it be:      url(r'^'old-link'/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='new-link/'), name='old-link'),

Comment: Yes, should be like that.

Comment: ok so i have tried implementing and deploying this and I'm still getting a 404 error on the page I'm trying to redirect from. IM using the following line:

url(r'^services/accidental-damage-restorations/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='services/contents-restoration/accidental-damage-restoration/'), name='services/accidental-damage-restorations/'),

Is this wrong still? If i code it as you mentioned, i.e.:

url(r'^'services/accidental-damage-restorations/'$', RedirectView.as_view(url='services/contents-restoration/accidental-damage-restoration/'), name='services/accidental-damage-restorations/'),

Comment: This causes the site to fall over and i get the following error:

url(r'^'services/accidental-damage-restorations/'$', RedirectView.as_view(url='services/contents-restoration/accidental-damage-restoration/'), name='services/accidental-damage-restorations/'),

                  ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: you misspelled  the url,    look at `'^'` you have an extra `'`

Comment: so it should be:

url(r'^services/accidental-damage-restorations/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='services/contents-restoration/accidental-damage-restoration/'), name='services/accidental-damage-restorations/'),

Comment: I just tried deploying the above but this still doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Anyone got any further thoughts on this please?